# Were any of the Apollo astronauts smokers and did that cause any problems?

Tags: nasa, apollo-program, astronauts, health, astronaut-lifestyle

Onboard the Apollo capsule, the astronauts probably weren’t allowed to smoke because of the risk. Apollo 1 blew up because of a small spark in a pure oxygen environment. Even though NASA changed the air in the Apollo spacecraft, there was still risk. Were any of the Apollo astronauts smokers and if so, were there any incidents where they were craving a cigarette, but couldn’t get one?

Comment: Apollo throughout the entire program ran on almost pure oxygen atmosphere, The changes were to construction and materials, but the risk of fire was permanent... and if an astronaut tried to light a cigarette, it would have burned all to ash in the pure oxygen faster than one could take a swig of smoke.

Comment: Where astronauts usually work it can be soddin' inconvenient to step outside for a coupla puffs...

Comment: It was the 1960's, everybody smoked, and those that didn't still got the equivalent second-hand because indoor rooms were more cigarette smoke than breathable air

Comment: For themselves or others? For themselves, well, it part of the reason that Glenn wasn't first human in space.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the early years of the Space program, smoking everywhere was considered normal. But NASA was ahead of its time. After members of the "[Original Seven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_Seven)" were seen smoking on TV, NASA was concerned about the squeaky-clean image the astronauts and urged the [astronauts to quit smoking](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/air-space-magazine/when-nasa-ordered-astronauts-quit-smoking-180951348/).

Wally Schirra quit before his Apollo 7 flight.

So in the sources I can find, the smoking was "only" a public image issue. All the astronauts seem to have had enough common sense not to smoke where it would be dangerous (ignoring the fact that smoking in itself is dangerous for the smokers and the people around them).

Comment: Even hardcore two pack a day smokers generally have enough common sense to know when not to light up. The one exception I know of is when I worked for a company that built a device that went into the flames of a spewing failed oil rig. Nobody previously had studied what exactly comes out. I called the person we had sent to help with our device and asked whether these people are as crazy as depicted. He replied that no, these were rock solid workers, but then said "wait a second." A guy whose clothing completely reeked of petroleum had just walked past, sat down, and calmly lit a cigarette.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact don’t worry I approved your edits. It has been changed

Comment: @TheRocketfan I was sure you would - it is just annoying that SE won't allow a low rep user to make a small change. I understand not allowing any changes without approval, but why limit to only *large* changes? Makes no sense.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact this might be in interest to you https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2953/is-there-a-way-to-give-someone-the-edit-privilege-before-they-reach-1000-rep

Comment: Might also be worth noting that these were military pilots - even if they were chainsmoking fiends, they would already have been used to time and place restrictions.

Comment: A friend of mine who used to work at the big Sun oil refinery in South Philadelphia told me this story.  She was inspecting a gasholder, which is a cylindrical building for storing flammable gas.  The roof is slightly convex, and as she crested the roof,  she saw there was a worker sitting on the other side, _smoking a cigarette_.  He tried to avoid being caught by swallowing his cigarette, but it was too late, and he lost his job that day.

Answer (score 23):

[image]

Buzz Aldrin with (presumably unlit) pipe. Gemini 12 photo S66-62984

Comment: And a nice slide rule…

Comment: Cool pic, but how does this answer the question?

Comment: @FreeMan: it seems more than likely than someone who has taken a pipe to space with him for a photo smokes said pipe, doesn't it?

Comment: Did said pipe cause problems, @JackAidley? That's what the OP was asking about.

Comment: And, in fact, newspaper reports from the time describe him smoking his "ever-lit corncob pipe" ( https://cdnc.ucr.edu/?a=d&d=DS19690715.2.59&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-------- ) and photos exist of him smoking ( https://www.ebay.com/itm/374367032042 )

Comment: @FreeMan True, there is a side question asked about that, but the primary question is about whether any of them smoked

Comment: Interesting. I'm wondering if it eased him into the right state of mind or some such...

Comment: It most probably has not even tabacco inside. You don't want loose stuf in microgravity. Because every little bit floating around has the potential of getting into to life support system or into the lungs of the astronaut. The "corned beef sandwich incident" didn't go down too well so smoking would have mad a much bigger stirr.

Comment: I think it'd be hilarious if the pipe just blew soap bubbles, but I imagine that would be potentially bad for any electronics in the capsule...

Answer (score 2):

Some astronauts did smoke, see the embedded *[Why you can’t talk about the Moon landing without mentioning cigarettes video in](https://www.fastcompany.com/90359002/why-you-cant-talk-about-the-moon-landing-without-mentioning-cigarettes)*. Some of the original Mercury astronauts can be seen smoking at the press conference announcing the astronauts. Also see, *[When NASA Told Its Astronauts to Quit Smoking](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/air-space-magazine/when-nasa-ordered-astronauts-quit-smoking-180951348/)*